# Not able to clone private repo using dockerfile

Tags: github, docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker, so was trying all basic stuff.

I have used following dockerfile to generate my working docker images

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER Alok Agarwal "alok.alok.com"

RUN apt-get update

#Install git 
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh/

ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN chmod 700 /root/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN git clone git@github.com:user/user.git

EXPOSE 80
```

I am able to clone my repo in my local system using ssh but when doing from docker its giving

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I have put my id_rsa file same place where my dockerfile reside but still doesnt know why it is continuously failing.

Am I missing any basic step.

Advance Thanks for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at my example, I have a **private** `ssh` key in the directory where I `dockerize` app(`ssh_keys/id_rsa`), and **public** key I have already upload to the private repo:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER Alok Agarwal "alok.alok.com"

RUN apt-get update

#Install git 
RUN apt-get install -y git

RUN /bin/bash -l -c "mkdir /root/.ssh"
ADD ssh_keys/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 700 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN echo "Host github.com\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> /root/.ssh/config 
RUN mkdir -p /www/app
RUN git clone git@github.com:my_private_repo/repo.git /www/app
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Just wanted to know do I need to make ssh_keys folder in same location as docker file. It gave me ssh_keys/id_rsa: no such file or directory

Comment: `ADD` take file from current dir and put it in to `docker` container. That's the same key should be persisted in `github` remote repo and in this directory and yes you need to make ssh_keys folder in same location as docker file.

Comment: Have done that still no luck giving permission denied issue. Is there a way to debug same

Comment: I am getting this error Cloning into project
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,1.1.1.1' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.  
can u please elaborate your first comment looks like I am not understanding it correctly

Comment: for github you need **public** key `id_rsa.pub` upload it to the github remote repo, when **private** key `id_rsa` copy to the `ssh_keys` dir when `docker` can `ADD` that private key. thats it.

Comment: before `git clone ...` try `RUN ssh -T -v git@github.com` it is show you `verbose` ssh connection between docker and github, may help to debug a problem. if you ssh connection success you should see something like `Hi .....! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access. `

Comment: I got the message Hi .....! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Comment: @AlokAgarwal thats mean you have a success authorization on github. Now try `git clone .....`